# Android SHared Preference?

Tags: android

I have listview and in that i have textview which will be changed automatically as NA to A .I used shared preference to get those data which is inside based adapter .It is fetching data but the value is not changing the value inside shared preference . If it is NA it will be changed to A once the list view Item is viewed but it still showing NA only .Can any one help how to update value SharedPreferences settings=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctxt);

```
    Editor editor=settings.edit();
    editor.putString("publisheddate",publisheddate);
    editor.putString("validity",validity);
    editor.putString("accessstatus",accessstatus);
```

Here accessstatus will change the value

Comment: did you called commit() on editor?

Comment: s i called editor.commit() at the end also.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call

```
editor.commit();
```

at the end.

Comment: i used that at the end but anyway value is not getting changed

Comment: Did you try [logging](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html) the values you get from your SharedPreferences? Your code seems correct, your problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

you need to commit the shared preferences. try like this code.

```
   lblTextViewOne.setText(editText1.getText());    
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferencesFileName", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = settings.edit();
    preferencesEditor.putString("OurText", editText1.getText().toString());
    preferencesEditor.commit();
```